# Is in BASH a way to move files matching "regexed wildcard"?

Tags: regex, bash, shell

Let's say I have this content:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 jirislav jirislav       4096 srp 17 20:31 Forrest Gump
-rw-r--r--  1 jirislav jirislav  491866996 srp 18 19:57 Forrest
-rw-r--r--  1 jirislav jirislav  216513381 srp 18 20:00 Forrest2
-rw-r--r--  1 jirislav jirislav      26131 srp 18 20:01 Forrest-min
-rw-r--r--  1 jirislav jirislav     215131 srp 18 20:01 mess-1
-rw-r--r--  1 jirislav jirislav    6211341 srp 18 20:03 bigger-mess
-rw-r--r--  1 jirislav jirislav   37225110 srp 18 20:05 largest-mess
```

And I want to **move *Forrest*, *Forrest2* & *Forrest-min* into *Forrest Gump* directory without specifying more than one input path** and I want to do it without using *find* command.

I mean - is there any way to move (using *mv* cmd) everything that matches this regex?:

```
mv Forrest[^\ ]* Forrest\ Gump
```

I know I can't write this regular expression with *mv* in bash like this, but there is already support written for wildcard, so I suppose there could be a possibility of specifying what I **don't want to match** while using asterisk.

### SOLUTION from @anubhava

Using `extglob` you can do:

```
shopt -s extglob

mv Forrest*([! ]) Forrest\ Gump
```

In `extglob` pattern `*([! ])` will match anything but spaces.

### EDIT

Note that in Debian jessie is extglob turned on by default, so you don't have to remember to turn the shell option on.

Comment: With mv from coreutils: `mv Forrest* "Forrest Gump"` and ignore the error.

Comment: `mv $(ls | egrep re_pattern) destination` but it won't quote the output before passing it to make.

Comment: @Cyrus nice workaround :) - I haven't thought of that, but _anubhava_ have showed me what I wanted to know - how to use regex with all possible bash commands

Comment: @Harvey, your solution is creating another shell environment, which is working, but if you ever want to make use of autocomplete of <Tab>, then you're stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `extglob` you can do:

```
shopt -s extglob

mv Forrest*([! ]) Forrest\ Gump
```

In `extglob` pattern `*([! ])` will match anything but spaces.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!! :)) thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

Not a regex, but it is a single(sort-of) pattern. From the [Pattern Matching section of `man bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
$ ls -1
Forrest
Forrest Gump
Forrest-min
Forrest2
$ ls Forrest@(|2|-min)
Forrest     Forrest-min Forrest2
```

It appears that you need the `extglob` shell option enabled for this to work: `shopt -s extglob` (thanks [@Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy)). It appears that my version of bash via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) on OS X enables this by default.

Comment: I've never seen that syntax.  Interesting.

Comment: @BrianVandenberg, it's an extglob. Not enabled out-of-the-box, but an available feature.

Comment: @Harvey, you should at least document enabling extglobs.

Comment: I don't recall ever enabling them.

Comment: It actually is a regex, it just uses a different syntax.

Comment: Both regular expressions and (extended) patterns are two different syntaxes for matching a string using a deterministic finite automaton. They perform roughly the same task, but it's not technically correct to say that an extended pattern *is* a regular expression.

Comment: Mac OS X does not enable extended pattern matching by default.

Comment: @chepner A regular expression is a mathematical construct, and extglob and ERE are both equivalent ascii syntax to express them. You can argue that the term should be "defines" and not "is", but then the same is true for ERE.

Comment: @chepner Updated re: extglob not set by default. I'm using bash from Homebrew.

Comment: So am I. Homebrew installs the software, but not any additional configuration files that I am aware of. You might want to figure out which file is setting the `extglob` option, if only to be aware of what files `bash` is using on startup.

Comment: Apparently, it comes from sourcing Homebrew's bash_completion: `. $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion`

Comment: The more I learn about bash, the more I love it <3 - btw isn't out there some kind of interactive tutorial for learning all of it's features?

Answer (score 0):

You can use brace expansion (I assume your objection is having to type `Forrest` multiple times):

```
mv Forrest{,2,-min} Forrest\ Gump
```